# laravel ajax pass multiple variables to controller?

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5

I need to pass 4 variables to controller so that I can do what I want to do with it, however I get an error:

> Missing argument 1 for
>   App\Http\Controllers\ProfileController::getGoogle()

Here's my Controller:

```
function getGoogle($lat, $lng, $destinationLat, $destinationLng) {
    print_r($lat);
    print_r($lng);
    print_r($destinationLat);
    print_r($destinationLng);
}
```

and ajax:

```
function getDirections(lat, lng, destinationLat, destinationLng) {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/google/',
        type: 'post',
        data: { 
            lat: lat,
            lng: lng,
            destinationLat: destinationLat,
            destinationLng: destinationLng
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() { alert('hello!'); },
        error: function() { alert('boo!'); },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
    });
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('google/', 'ProfileController@getGoogle');
```

Comment: Please show your google route.

Comment: code has been updated

Comment: I think your route is wrong because you can pass 4 parameter in your getGoogle()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't passing any parameter via the `url` and is passing via ajax `POST` params so you need to change your controller method definition to

```
function getGoogle() {
    print_r(Input::get('lat'));
    print_r(Input::get('lng'));
    print_r(Input::get('destinationLat'));
    print_r(Input::get('destinationLng'));
}
```

Comment: how come it is returning error function despite giving me the right output?

Comment: there is no error to be honest, in developer tools I can see the output but in ajax error: is called instead of success

Comment: What is the response code that you are getting? Maybe because the ajax is expecting an JSON response and you are not returning it an valid JSON

Comment: yeap you were right, after returning json everything is fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You are actually sending POST variables to the controller, but you are accepting them in controller as GET variables,if you want to read the variables, your controller should be like this:

```
function getGoogle(Request $request) {
    print_r($request->input('lat'));
    print_r($request->input('lng'));
    print_r($request->input('destinationLat'));
   print_r($request->input('destinationLng'));
```

}

Remember to import Request as `use Illuminate\Http\Request;`